# Scope of variables in C

Tags: c, scope

I have a program that has a variable called best_cost which is defined outside of all of the functions. I then have a function called compare_costs which can change the value of best_cost, and I have best_cost being printed in main().
As it is right now it outputs 1000000, which tells me that the scope of the compare_costs function can't change the value of best_costs. I used a debugger and saw that best_cost is being changed inside compare_costs. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
int best_cost = 1000000;

int main {

    compare_costs(new_cost);

    printf("%d", best_cost);

}

void compare_costs(nc) 
{
    if(nc < best_cost) {
        best_cost = nc;
    }
}
```

Do I need to use pointers? If so can you give me a simplified version of how to implement it as pointers?

Also, I should note that this is very simplified code of what I'm actually using. There's a reason I didn't just pass best_cost into the compare_costs function and have it return a best_cost.

here is the whole code: http://pastebin.com/khs2jcaF

Comment: int main(), sorry I wrote this simplified code without really looking it over

Comment: I think something was lost in the simplification.

Comment: Your example won't compile because new_cost is not defined.

Comment: Basically my question boils down to: how do I use a variable that has file scope and change that value inside a function. Sorry if I'm not being very clear

Comment: You can change global variables inside functions.  Your example doesn't demonstrate the actual problem you are having.

Comment: You'll want to give an example that actually compiles and shows the problem you are talking about.

Comment: ok ill upload the whole program to pastebin http://pastebin.com/khs2jcaF

Comment: The variable best_cost can be changed by any function present in the file

Comment: In your pastebin example, you have a best_cost variable declared inside main.

Comment: Over here http://pastebin.com/khs2jcaF best_cost is shadowed. It's defined at global and local scope levels.

Comment: The best_cost defined inside the main will ultimately hide the original global variable

Comment: You're basically printing the local value and changing the global one.

Comment: If the code above compiled without warnings, you need a better compiler or you need to use more warnings.  It is very, very sloppy coding style to use the 'void compare_costs(nc) { ... }` notation instead of `void compare_costs(nc) int nc; { ... }` or `void compare_costs(int nc) { ... }`.  The first is really old school C; the second is more like recommended K&R C; the third became standard in 1989 and should be used in all modern code.

Comment: The code in pastebin is too long. The code in your question doesn't exhibit the problem. Please take the code from pastebin, pare it down to a small example *that exhibits the problem*, and edit the resulting code into your question. (Yes, your problem has been solved, but the question should be useful to future readers.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that best_cost is also defined in main().

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove `int best_cost;` from main()..

Answer (score 0):

Please edit the question to properly represent the state of the problem. As it stands the problem posted is not in sync to the code posted within http://pastebin.com/khs2jcaF